# How to use global variables declared in one drl file among the other files?

Tags: drools

we have requirement where i will declare all the required variables in one drools drl file and i would like to use those declared variables in other drl files.

we will get a customized xml file which will be not be understood by drools so what we are doing is first we are converting it to drools BRL which is understandable format and then using the droools API, we are converting it into drool drl file.

In the xml files, we will get objects along with their respective types.  what we are planning here is we would like to use the global variable concept of drools so that we will declare all the possible objects in one drl file statically and then use those variables in other drl files(which get translated from customized xml to drool BRl and then drools drl)

Comment: malledugu: did you come up with a solution to this? I am looking to do this as well?